# Finding isomorphisms among groups

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

The lecture notes I'm working through pose an exercise to find groups that are isomorphic to each other or to subgroups of other groups. The groups listed so far are:

> 1. The trivial group $\{e\}$
> 2. Numerical systems under addition: $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{C}$ with their usual addition.
> 3. Any group with two elements $\{e,x\}$ (with the only possible multiplication table: $ex = xe = x$, $ee = e$, and $xx = e$.
> 4. $\mathbb{Z}/n = \{0,1, \ldots, n-1\}$ with addition mod $n$
> 5. Non-zero elements $\mathbb{Q}^{*}$, $\mathbb{R}^{*}$, $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ with multiplication
> 6. $S^1$, the complex unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$
> 7. Permutations of any set $A$, denoted $\mathrm{Perm}(A)$
> 8. $S_n$, the symmetric group on $n$ letters (the above with $A = \{1, \ldots, n\}$
> 9. The general linear group and special linear group of matrices
> 10. Products, finite and infinite, of groups
> 11. Direct sums of groups
> 12. $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} = [0,1)$ with addition mod $1$

My goal is to find as many isomorphisms as I can between these groups, including subgroups thereof. That is, if $H \lhd G$, then $H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$.
There is only one group of order $1$ and one group of order $2$, up to isomorphism, so I don't think I'm missing any with those. As $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$, I can say that

> 1. $(\mathbb{Z}, +) \lhd (\mathbb{Q}, +) \lhd (\mathbb{R}, +) \lhd (\mathbb{C}, +)$

and, since the integers do not form a multiplicative group:

> 2. $(\mathbb{Q}^{*}, \times) \lhd (\mathbb{R}^{*}, \times) \lhd (\mathbb{C}^{*}, \times)$

Taking $A$ to be any $n$-element set, we can say that:

> 3. $\mathrm{Perm}(A) \cong S_n$

As $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$, we can say that:

> 4. $\mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{R}) \lhd \mathrm{GL}_n (\mathbb{C})$

As $S^1 : = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| = 1\} \subset \mathbb{C}^{*}$, we have

> 5. $(S^1, \times) \subset (\mathbb{C}^{*}, \times)$

By definition, a direct sum is an "infinite tuple" $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, )$ where $a_i \in G_i$ and all but finitely many terms are the identity. A direct product lifts the latter restriction, so any direct sum is a subgroup of the corresponding direct product:

> 6. $\bigoplus G_i \lhd \prod G_i$

For $1 \leq i \leq n$, if $H_i \lhd G_i$, then every tuple $(h_1, \ldots, h_n)$ of elements of $H_i$ is an element of $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n G_i$, so we have:

> 7. $\forall 1 \leq i \leq n, \; H_i \lhd G_i \implies \prod\limits_{i=1}^n H_i \lhd \prod\limits_{i=1}^n G_i$.

If $F \cong F'$ as fields, then I should be able to write down an isomorphism between $\mathrm{GL}_n (F)$ and $\mathrm{GL}_n (F')$, where the map sends an element $A \in \mathrm{GL}_n (F)$ to its image, entry-by-entry, under the isomorphism between $F$ and $F'$.

> 8. $\mathrm{GL}_n (F) \cong \mathrm{GL}_n (F')$

The $n$th roots of unit, $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z|^n = 1\}$ form a cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{\star}$, and any cyclic subgroup of size $n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n$:

> 9. $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z|^n = 1\} \cong \mathbb{Z}/n$.

I'm not able to think of any others, though there's a hint in the notes to consider $\mathbb{Z}/n$, $\mathbb{C}^{*}$, and $\mathrm{GL}_2 (\mathbb{R})$. I'd appreciate if someone could help with this, either in providing feedback on what I wrote above or in pointing out some isomorphisms involving these above three groups or isomorphisms I missed.

Comment: You might want to look at $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, and think about what it looks like geometrically when you take the interval $[1,0]$ and then fold it so $0$ and $1$ are glued together (which is sort of what $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is).

Comment: Gosh, you've done a lot of good work! For $\Bbb C^*$ and $\mathrm{GL}_2(\Bbb R)$, remember that you can think of "multiplication by $z = a + ib$" as a geometric transformation of the plane. Can you also capture this transformation with a matrix?

Comment: This is far too broad.

Comment: @CaptainLama Is the isomorphism you had in mind the map $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to S^1$ sending $[0,1) \mapsto e^{i 2\pi t}$? I'm not sure if I have to alter the map somewhat, but I think this gives a complex number of modulus $1$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Is this related to conformal matrices? I know there is a field isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}$ and the set of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$, the image under $\mathbb{C}$ of which is the complex under $a + bi$. Can I argue that this is an isomorphism under either addition or multiplication?

Comment: Others I might mention: $\{e,x\}\cong\Bbb Z/2$, $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\cong\Bbb C$, if $n\mid m$ then $\Bbb Z/n$ embeds in $\Bbb Z/m$, $S_n$ embeds in $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ ("permutation matrices"), if $n, m$ coprime then $\Bbb Z/n \times \Bbb Z/m\cong\Bbb Z/nm$, $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)\times\mathrm{GL}_m(F)$ embeds in $\mathrm{GL}_{n+m}(F)$ (same for SL), $\Bbb Q^*\cong\Bbb Z/2\times\bigoplus_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb Z$, $\Bbb C^*\cong\Bbb R_+^*\times S^1$, ... A good related exercise is proving some of these groups *aren't* isomorphic! Careful though - you won't be able to prove $\Bbb C^*\ncong S^1$..

Comment: @BradG., exactly right. That gives an isomorphism from $\Bbb C^*$ to a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\Bbb R)$. It also gives an isomorphism from $\Bbb C$ to a group of $2 \times 2$ matrices, but that group doesn't live inside the general linear group!

Comment: @BradG. Yes you are right, this does give an isomorphism $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\to S^1$ if you see $S^1$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$.